# Boot failure after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, 15.04

I have **Sony Vaio** Fit computer with a dual boot setup of Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.10.

After upgrading to 15.04, booting into Linux fails with a number of '`builtin file not found`' errors.

I tried toggling Secure Boot but that doesn't help.

The **boot-repair** info is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/12101145. If anybody has a suggestions, I would appreciate.

TIA

Comment: Can you get to grub ( OS selection screen ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe grub is configured badly:

Create a super grub2 disk (http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) usb drive.

Boot from the usb drive and try to start ubuntu.
If it works, run   `update-grub` and try booting without the usb drive.